# Postgres pgSQL Stored Procedure - Cache Results

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have the following PLV8 stored procedure that defines a function that does a lookup on some key/values - and caches the lookup table as a Map in memory:

```
create function ref(id smallint) returns text
    immutable
    language plv8
as
$$
// Cache the ref data if necessary
if (! plv8.ref) {
    const data = plv8.execute(`
        SELECT id, name FROM ref.country
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, name FROM ref.employees
        UNION ALL
        ...
        SELECT id, name FROM ref.revenue
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, name FROM ref.sub_market
    `);
    plv8.ref = [];
    data.forEach(function(item) { plv8.ref[item.id] = item.name });
}
return plv8.ref[id];
$$;
```

This works really well, and is much faster and less verbose than doing joins into the reference tables.

How would I write a similar Stored Procedure in **pgSQL**? One that caches the lookup in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You use a temporary table for that. If you set `temp_buffers` high enough, the table will be cached in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom user setting variables in PLpgSQL (and in any other language). These variables are designed for Postgres and Postgres extension configuration, but can be used for holding some session data too. It is not designed for long or very complex data - only string can be stored there. [See](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE) functions `set_config` and `current_setting`.

PLpgSQL has not other global storage than tables. So you cannot to write procedure's data cache well in PLpgSQL. But PLPerl or PLPython can be used for this purpose.